# Baffling menu when installing RKHunter

Tags: package-management, postfix, rkhunter

Someone advised me to install a program called rkhunter for security.  I've tried to do so, just using the apt command at the terminal, but am presented with a weird message about e-mail servers.

I have no idea what any of these options mean and so haven't dared to select any in case I gum up my Internet connection or something.  What should I select?

It's possible that some other package called `postfix`, which was a required package that installed along with rkhunter, might be behind this rather than rkhunter itself.  The word "postfix" appears on the menu.

Annoyingly, not only can I not get rkhunter going until this is completed, but it appears that `dpkg` is gummed up until it's completed and I can't install or uninstall anything else either!
Whenever I try to run, for instance, `apt install`, the terminal shows an error message referring to dpkg.  After this has happened once or twice, it shows a different error message suggesting running "`dpkg --configure -a`".
When I do that, dpkg appears to sort itself out, but then, when I try to use `apt install` again (for any package), it goes back to trying to install rkhunter, scrolling through the usual "X% complete" messages and then displaying the cryptic menu, which cannot be closed until it is answered!

Answer (score 2):

You are right, `rkhunter` wants a mail transport agent and it tries to install the large and complicated `postfix` to get one.

To avoid this, you can install the tiny `nullmailer` instead and that will satisfy the mail transport agent dependency. Once that's done, install `rkhunter`.

However, first you need to fix your `dpkg` problems. Please [edit] your question and give details about what's gone wrong there: error messages, etc.

Comment: Well, I can't, actually, because after remaining jammed for days no matter what I did, dpkg has for no apparent reason un-jammed itself, and rkhunter has spontaneously stopped asking the cryptic questions about servers and is working fine.  So I didn't have a chance to try your instructions, but thanks all the same, would've been just what I was after if that hadn't happened.  Am editing original posting to add details of what happened to dpkg in case anyone else strikes this glitch in future.